# Installation of software remotely without file transfer

Tags: installation, remote-desktop, file-transfer

Is it possible to install software on a remote machine WITHOUT transferring the installation file into the remote machine AT ANY POINT in time?

I got a comment that the question is very general and I need to edit this question and make it clearer. I will try. I have an installation executable. I need to install the application remotely. For this, I use team viewer to connect, then copy the setup, then run it, set the installation parameters, see if everything is working fine and then delete the copied file. In this process, if there is a network disconnection (which happens quite often in my area), then the setup executable is left in the remote machine which I do not want. Hence this question. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: This is an extremely broad and generic question that almost certainly isn’t the real thing you are trying to answer. Please [edit] your question and provide detail about what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Technically no. The installation file is always transferred during the installation. But there's a different between manual transfer and background transfer. If it's background transfer then it looks like it's not really transferred... For instance, you can do something like `msiexec.exe /i https://just-install.github.io/stable/just-install.msi`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mapped a network drive, you could run it from there.

```
net use \\servername\folder\ /PERSISTENT:NO /user:blah
```

password

No drive letter would show up.

When the computer reboots the connection would be lost.

If you had access to the server you could force disconnect them at any time.

The physical install would not be on there machine.

However, most programs decompress themselves into temp folders so some traces would be left behind.

Depending on the size of the install and speed of the network connection this could be slow.